# MSBuild MSBuildCommunityTasks Task Time

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuildcommunitytasks

I have a MSBuild project and I want the current date to be added to a zip file that I am creating.

I am using the MSBuildCommunityTasks.

```
<!-- Import the CommunityTasks Helpper -->
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />
```

On the website http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/ I can see a task called time.  I have not been able to find doc on how to use Time.

Comment: The MSBuild tasks included a CHM file in the directory you installed it in. Whenever I have to use MSBuildCommunityTasks I always keep that file open.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[In msbuild 4 you can now](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2010/04/02/msbuild-property-functions.aspx)

```
$([Namespace.Type]::Method(..parameters…))
$([Namespace.Type]::Property)
$([Namespace.Type]::set_Property(value))
```

so I am using

```
$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(`yyyy.MMdd`))
```

those ticks around the format are backticks not `'`

Comment: More Date/time tostring formats here: http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

Answer (score 21):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Project DefaultTargets="Deploy" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>

  <!-- Include MSBuild tasks here -->

  <ItemGroup>     
      <DefaultExclude Include="****" />           
  </ItemGroup>


 <Target Name="Deploy" >

    <Time Format="yyyy-MM-dd">
    <Output TaskParameter="FormattedTime" PropertyName="buildDate" />
    </Time>

    <Message Text="Deploying ...."></Message>   

    <Copy  SourceFiles="@(DeploymentFiles)" DestinationFolder="C:\CCNET\$(buildDate)\bin\" />

</Target>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maslow's answer is correct (I can't comment on it or I would); I would only add to it that you have to be careful when implicitly calling System.DateTime.Parse.

A parsed string value like `$([System.DateTime]::Parse("1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z")` doesn't seem to end up with a Kind of `DateTimeKind.Utc`.

But you can use [nested property functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx#Anchor_1) to make it work; like this (to get the Unix timestamp):

`$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.Subtract($([System.DateTime]::Parse("1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z").ToUniversalTime())).TotalSeconds.ToString("F0"))`